# How to translate this equation to C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to translate this equation to `c++` code:

```
x = (10π)/(a+b)*sinC^3+3(ln a)(tan C)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h> using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float x, y, z, a, b, C, PI;
    cout << endl << "Enter value a=";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter value b=";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter angle C in degrees=";
    cin >> C;
    PI = 3.1416;
    C = C * PI / 180;
    x = ((10 * PI) / (a + b)) * pow(sin(C), 3);
    +3 * (log(a)) * (tan(C));
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(4);
    cout << endl << "x = " << x;
    cout << endl << "y = " << y;
    cout << endl << "z = " << z;
}
```

Comment: ***Show Code***  What have you attempted?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 float x,y,z,a,b,C,PI;
 cout<<endl<<"Enter value a=";
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"Enter value b=";
 cin>>b;
 cout<<"Enter angle C in degrees=";
 cin>>C;
 
 PI=3.1416;
 C=C*PI/180;
 
 x=((10*PI)/(a+b))*pow(sin(C),3);+3*(log(a))*(tan(C));
 y=0;
 z=0;
 
 
 cout<<fixed<<setprecision(4);
 cout<<endl<<"x = "<<x;
 cout<<endl<<"y = "<<y;
 cout<<endl<<"z = "<<z;
}

Comment: Thanks for the code. I attempted to improve your question and format the code.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is with this code? Does it return wrong values? The reason I ask is this is usually required for a good question.

Answer (score 3):

**Pi** is defined in math.h, as `M_PI`

**Sine** is defined in math.h as `double sin(double)`

**Tangent** is defined in math.h as `double tan(double)`

**Natural Log** is defined in math.h as `double ln(double)`

**Power** is defined in math.h as `double pow(double,double)`

---

You wrote:

```
x = ((10 * PI) / (a + b)) * pow(sin(C), 3);
    +3 * (log(a)) * (tan(C));
```

The second 1/2 of that (starting at `+3`) is not part of the original expression, which ended with a semi-colon.

Try:

```
x = ((10 * PI) / (a + b)) * pow(sin(C), 3) + 3 * (log(a)) * (tan(C));
```

Also, be sure you understand the difference between `log`*(base10)* and `ln`*(natural log)*.